# How correct get image from controller

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

Im using React and asp net creating component PostList of images. On some sites I see they have src on they image like:

```
<img src="/snapshots/139/ec5b8456-4c7a-4b29-b37b-1dcb2e23f477.jpeg">
```

I have in wwwroot folder named "Images",how to do like this

When I paste in src "/Images/1.png" it doesnt work, but if I paste full path like
"https://localhost:44382/Images/1.png" its work

I have controller and models:

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(List<GetPostDto>))]
[HttpGet("Get")]
public IActionResult GetPosts()
{
  return Ok(_postService.GetPosts());
}
```

```
public class GetPostDto
{
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public string ImagePath => $"/Images/{Id}.png";
 public long LikeCount { get; set; }
 public long ViewCount { get; set; }
}
```

and front view

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

interface IPost {
    id: number,
    likeCount: number,
    viewCount: number,
    imagePath: string
}

interface IPostPreview {
    post: IPost
}

export default function PostPreview({ post }: IPostPreview) {
    return (
        <Link to={`post/${post.id}`} className='h-[200px] w-[200px] flex border'>
            <img alt='qwe' src={`https://localhost:44382${post.imagePath}`} className='flex justify-between px-3 w-full h-full'>
            </img>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is when you design the api. Return the data in a form that does not need to be changed in the client.
When you use relative paths, you may see different behavior in different technologies (React,flutter, ...). In addition, in that case, you need to do these things in every app client (React,flutter, ...) you added , which is not correct

I don't know how the `PostService` class is designed. But I will provide a solution for use in the `controller`, which you can add to `PostService` more optimally in the future:

```cs
public class GetPostDto
{
   //... other properties

   public string ImagePath { get; set; }
  
}
```

and change controller code as follows :

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(List<GetPostDto>))]
[HttpGet("Get")]
public IActionResult GetPosts()
{
    var posts = _postService.GetPosts();
    posts.ToList().ForEach(x=>x.ImagePath= $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/Images/{x.Id}.png");
    return Ok(posts);
}
```